# UserAccountsDrawerHeader CircleAvatar suddenly not showing

Tags: flutter, dart

Suddenly the CircleAvatar has started not to show in the emulator or on phone, not sure why. Code hasn't changed, working with Android Studio on windows.

Tried copying to new project and fresh install of android studio.

```
UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text('Test'),
                accountEmail: Text('test@gmail.com'),
                currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text('DB'),
                ),
              ),
```

No errors.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG8Tt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the issue you stating.

[image]

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
    );
  }

  Widget AppDrawer() {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
      UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      accountName: Text('Test'),
      accountEmail: Text('test@gmail.com'),
      currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        child: Text('DB'),
      ),
    ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the error was on my end. By replacing the code inside of the user_accounts_drawer_header.dart file, I was able to rectify the problem.